# Redirect to a specified page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way through which i can have a javascript on a page to redirect any url that's present on the page to some specific site.

For example on a HTML page i have say 10 urls present. Can i add a javascript to the HTML page  so that if anyone clicks on any url on that page, it gets redirected to the a specified page.

Thanks.

EDIT::

My scenario is i have some 13k links on a page and i do highlighting of terms on the page, even if any link is also clicked on the page, the word gets highlighted on that page. In order to do that i process each url and add some more info to it to go thought my server perl script which does the job of highlighting. But now due to large number of links on page, it takes time to process the page and page is rendered after a long time. So i want to have a javascript which can pass any link by adding info to my perl script on server.

I tried doing it server side my breaking page into pieces and processing in parallel but not much improvement.

Any other solution or suggestions are welcomed.
Appreciate your help in this regard.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel, a url, when clicked go to the link, if they are `<a href="http://www.link.com.br/">http://www.link.com.br/</a>`.

Comment: Please check my edit, hope its understandable. That's my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preventDefault` in the click event handler to prevent the default behavior(open the link), and use `location.href` to redirect to a new page.

if you're using jQuery:

```
$(".links").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    location.href = "http://google.com";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following jQuery block:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#urlId').live('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //Stops the link from opening
        window.location.href = "/specifiedPage"; // Changes the location of the page
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "protective glass" div in front of everything and handle the click event on that div. This has the advantage of not touching the page so after removing the div anything can go back to normal.

Only be sure to put a non-fully-transparent color on the div background because I've found that Internet Explorer ignores events if the div is fully transparent.

Something like `rgba(0,0,0,0.001)` is enough.